# How to determine primary swipe direction (using MultiTouch) in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, multi-touch, swipe

I'm trying to implement very simple swipe recognition on a touch screen using AS3.  I just need to know whether the swipe is to the left, right, top, or bottom.

First question: would this be easier to do using simple MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP, and simply calculate the distance(s) moved?

Or would it be easier to do using MultiTouch?

I see code for MultiTouch showing how to implement swipe detection and getting the direction thus:

```
        if (e.offsetY == 1) { 
    //User swiped towards bottom
    square_mc.y += 100; 
    }
    if (e.offsetY == -1) { 
    //User swiped towards top
    square_mc.y -= 100;
    }
            if (e.offsetX == 1) { 
    //User swiped towards right
    square_mc.x += 100; 
    }
    if (e.offsetX == -1) { 
    //User swiped towards left
    square_mc.x -= 100;
    }
```

but if you need to resolve to ONE direction (that is left OR up, right OR bottom, etc), how do you do that (and if offsetX and offsetY are true offsets, why are they checking for +1 and -1 only?  Or is this a function that is called often during the swipe?  I'm trying to get one COMPLETE swipe).

I'm thinking skipping MultiTouch might be simpler, but would welcome feedback.  Thanks!

Comment: it's actually alot easier using MultiTouch protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can answer your own question(s) by doing two things...

1 Re-read the tutorial that your code came from.. especially the section headed "Coding the gesture" http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3swipegesture/

2 Just experiment and learn from observing results. For example...

> but if you need to resolve to ONE direction (that is left OR.... how
>   do you do that?

Well what's wrong with this line in the code YOU provided `if (e.offsetX == -1) { square_mc.x -= 100; }`. Did you test it? Did square_mc not move left by 100 pixels when you swiped towards left direction? If it worked you have successfully "resolved" one direction, I guess. You can add the other `If` statements for other directions as needed.